# Asymptotics of the least common multiple of the first natural numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, prime-number-theorem

What is $$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(\mathrm{lcm}(1,2, \dots, n))}{n} \ \ ?$$

Comment: Limit exists and equals to $n$, it is equivalent form of Prime Numbers Theorem.

Comment: @FedorPetrov you probably meant $1$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Ah, of course! Sorry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is well-known that $\operatorname{lcm}(1,\ldots,n) = e^{\psi(n)}$, where $\psi$ is the Chebyshev's function. Since $\psi(x) = x + o(x)$, as $x \to +\infty$, (a form of the Prime Number Theorem) it follows that actually $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\log(\operatorname{lcm}(1,\ldots,n))}{n} = 1$. (See Part 1 of G. Tenenbaum - Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory).

Not really a MO question, in my opinion.

Comment: The fact that the question was formulated in this specific way suggests it's some sort of exercise/homework.

Comment: @Wojowu it is not. I have just guessed the asymptotics after some wolfram calculations. That's all.

Comment: @Pablo Certainly I believe you, but it almost always helps to read in the question what sort of work OP did on the problem before asking at MO.

Comment: I'm glad to have this here ! I've got an algorithm whose complexity is exactly this log(gcd(1,...,n)). It is more or less theoretical, since I dont know any machine able to run it for n larger than 64. Anyway, II expected it to have a much bigger complexity  than linear. I was surprised to see it working fast after implementing it. That's cool !

Answer (score 3):

Well, certainly $L=\text{lcm}(1,...,n)$ is divisible by $p^k\leq n$. We can take $k$ up to $[\log_p n]\geq \frac{\log n}{\log p}-1$. So $$\log L\geq \sum_{p\leq n}\left(\frac{\log n}{\log p}-1\right)\log p\approx n$$ by the Prime Number Theorem. So the lim sup should be 1.